# Ошибка при попытке оптимизации системы нелинейных уравнений

Tags: python

При попытке оптимизировать систему с использованием scipy.optimize.least_squares

```
x0 = np.ones(27)
def one_VI_set_012(x):
    gamma1 = x[0] + 1j*x[1]
    Zw1 = x[2] + 1j*x[3]
    gamma0 = x[4] + 1j*x[5]
    Zw0 = x[6] + 1j*x[7]
    len1 = x[8]
    len2 = len - x[8]
    I_left_f1 = x[9] * np.exp(1j*x[10]*np.pi/180)
    I_right_f1 = x[11] * np.exp(1j * x[12]*np.pi/180)
    V_f1 = x[13] * np.exp(1j * x[14]*np.pi/180)

    I_left_f2 = x[15] * np.exp(1j*x[16]*np.pi/180)
    I_right_f2 = x[17] * np.exp(1j * x[18]*np.pi/180)
    V_f2 = x[19] * np.exp(1j * x[20]*np.pi/180)

    I_left_f0 = x[21] * np.exp(1j*x[22]*np.pi/180)
    I_right_f0 = x[23] * np.exp(1j * x[24]*np.pi/180)
    V_f0 = x[25] * np.exp(1j * x[26]*np.pi/180)

    return [ \
    np.real(V_f1 - (Vbeg_1*np.cosh(gamma1*len1) - Ibeg_1*Zw1*np.sinh(gamma1*len1))),
    np.real(I_left_f1 - (-Vbeg_1*np.sinh(gamma1*len1)/Zw1 + Ibeg_1*np.cosh(gamma1*len1))),
    np.real(Vend_1 - (V_f1*np.cosh(gamma1*len2) - I_right_f1*Zw1*np.sinh(gamma1*len2))),
    np.real(Iend_1 - (-V_f1*np.sinh(gamma1*len2)/Zw1 + I_right_f1*np.cosh(gamma1*len2))),
    np.real(V_f2 - (Vbeg_2*np.cosh(gamma1*len1) - Ibeg_2*Zw1*np.sinh(gamma1*len1))),
    np.real(I_left_f2 - (-Vbeg_2*np.sinh(gamma1*len1)/Zw1 + Ibeg_2*np.cosh(gamma1*len1))),
    np.real(Vend_2 - (V_f2*np.cosh(gamma1*len2) - I_right_f2*Zw1*np.sinh(gamma1*len2))),
    np.real(Iend_2 - (-V_f2*np.sinh(gamma1*len2)/Zw1 + I_right_f2*np.cosh(gamma1*len2))),
    np.real(V_f0 - (Vbeg_0*np.cosh(gamma0*len1) - Ibeg_0*Zw0*np.sinh(gamma0*len1))),
    np.real(I_left_f0 - (-Vbeg_0*np.sinh(gamma0*len1)/Zw0 + Ibeg_0*np.cosh(gamma0*len1))),
    np.real(Vend_0 - (V_f0*np.cosh(gamma0*len2) - I_right_f0*Zw0*np.sinh(gamma0*len2))),
    np.real(Iend_0 - (-V_f0*np.sinh(gamma0*len2)/Zw0 + I_right_f0*np.cosh(gamma0*len2))),
    np.real((I_left_f1 - I_right_f1) - (I_left_f0 - I_right_f0)),
    np.real((I_left_f1 - I_right_f1) - (I_left_f2 - I_right_f2)),

    np.imag(V_f1 - (Vbeg_1*np.cosh(gamma1*len1) - Ibeg_1*Zw1*np.sinh(gamma1*len1))),
    np.imag(I_left_f1 - (-Vbeg_1*np.sinh(gamma1*len1)/Zw1 + Ibeg_1*np.cosh(gamma1*len1))),
    np.imag(Vend_1 - (V_f1*np.cosh(gamma1*len2) - I_right_f1*Zw1*np.sinh(gamma1*len2))),
    np.imag(Iend_1 - (-V_f1*np.sinh(gamma1*len2)/Zw1 + I_right_f1*np.cosh(gamma1*len2))),
    np.imag(V_f2 - (Vbeg_2*np.cosh(gamma1*len1) - Ibeg_2*Zw1*np.sinh(gamma1*len1))),
    np.imag(I_left_f2 - (-Vbeg_2*np.sinh(gamma1*len1)/Zw1 + Ibeg_2*np.cosh(gamma1*len1))),
    np.imag(Vend_2 - (V_f2*np.cosh(gamma1*len2) - I_right_f2*Zw1*np.sinh(gamma1*len2))),
    np.imag(Iend_2 - (-V_f2*np.sinh(gamma1*len2)/Zw1 + I_right_f2*np.cosh(gamma1*len2))),
    np.imag(V_f0 - (Vbeg_0*np.cosh(gamma0*len1) - Ibeg_0*Zw0*np.sinh(gamma0*len1))),
    np.imag(I_left_f0 - (-Vbeg_0*np.sinh(gamma0*len1)/Zw0 + Ibeg_0*np.cosh(gamma0*len1))),
    np.imag(Vend_0 - (V_f0*np.cosh(gamma0*len2) - I_right_f0*Zw0*np.sinh(gamma0*len2))),
    np.imag(Iend_0 - (-V_f0*np.sinh(gamma0*len2)/Zw0 + I_right_f0*np.cosh(gamma0*len2))),
    np.imag((I_left_f1 - I_right_f1) - (I_left_f0 - I_right_f0)),
    np.imag((I_left_f1 - I_right_f1) - (I_left_f2 - I_right_f2))]

root = least_squares(one_VI_set_012,x0)
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: написано же, нет разве? Не советуют функцию isfinite использовать для вводимых данных. Но я её в коде не вижу. На какую строчку-то жалоба?

Comment: Эта функция находится внутри least_squres.py. Ошибка в строке: root = least_squares(one_VI_set_012,x0)

Comment: Мне вообще не запустить. Нет np. Но, возможно, у вас тип в return из one_VI_set_012 не устраивает least_squares или isfinite. Попробуйте проверить соответствие типов.